# Error integrating simple GoogleMaps app with core app

Tags: android, google-maps, android-activity, android-intent

I'm doing my GPS app. Standalone app with GoogleMaps works smoothly (map intent is easy to invoke). I tried integrating it my core app (which has several other intents) and I'm having problem launching it.

I've tried this:

```
public class MapaG extends Activity {   
    public class MapaG1 extends MapActivity {

        private static final int latitudeE6= 50656428;
        private static final int longitudeE6 = 17899562;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.widokmapy);

            MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
            mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

            List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
            Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
            NakladkaNaMape itemizedOverlay = new NakladkaNaMape(drawable, this);

            GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(latitudeE6, longitudeE6);
            OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Witaj w Opolu", "Polska");
            itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
            mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

            MapController mapController = mapView.getController();

            mapController.animateTo(point);
            mapController.setZoom(12);
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

LogCat perspective gives me info that no Activity was found:

```
FATAL EXEPTION: main android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found handle Intent {act=praca.dyp.k.d.MAPAG}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm wondering why you are creating a MapActivity class inside an Activity? Remove the outer activity class declaration. Keep the MapActivity class. Use proper permissions in Manifest.

Comment: I've removed as you said, but still I'm receiving error No Activity found to handle Intent. manifest is was set before properly

Comment: Did you change the Java file name to the activity name? Is manifest file contains the same name of activity as ur map activity class name?

Comment: letter error with activity name in manifest.xml now it's fixed. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Did you add your MapAcitivity in your AndroindManifest.xml file?

You also need to include this in your manifest:

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

You can look here for a more detailed example:

[HelloWorld, MapActivity](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html)

Comment: i read, several tutorials. i have it working good when MapaG is main activity( in my fist app), but now i try to implement this class in my second app , and i cannot lunched Map Activity ( it's not my main now) [mainA-> otherA ->(err0r) ->MapaG]